# PostgreSQL Rolling Standard Deviation over time in single query

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

This may be an easily solvable question but I can't see an immediate solution. I am calling a PostgreSQL function which returns multiple columns, 2 of which are relevant to this question - a date column & a numeric field of return values. An example of the function call would be

```
SELECT curr_date, return_val 
  FROM schema.function_name($1,$2);
```

With example output such as

```
"2014-07-31";0.003767
"2014-08-07";-0.028531
"2014-08-14";0.020051
"2014-08-21";-0.003541
"2014-08-28";0.007766
"2014-09-04";-0.021926
"2014-09-11";0.026330
"2014-09-18";0.008137
"2014-09-25";-0.033303
"2014-10-02";0.030100
"2014-10-09";-0.012116
"2014-10-16";-0.017148
```

So on, so forth. The data will always return from this function with the dates ascending. What I would like to do is to use Postgres's **stddev_samp** function on every row, but only considering the return_value's from that row's date back in time. Something like:

```
SELECT curr_date, return_val,
     --stddev_samp(return_val) where curr_date <= curr_date of current row
  FROM schema.function_name($1,$2);
```

Naturally, if I calculated the sample deviation of the return_value's from 2014-07-31 to 2014-10-02 in the sample provided, it would differ slightly to calculating it using the result set from 2014-07-31 to any other date present. I know I could probably write another function which takes a numeric array as input and returns the standard deviation as output, and then call this in my query above, but I'm hoping someone may have a simpler approach which I'm just currently not seeing. If any other information is required, feel free to ask. I'm using version 10.7.

Comment: I think you are looking for a window funciton: `stddev_samp(return_val) over (order by curr_date)`

Comment: wow, as easy as that. That worked a charm. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the concise and extremely prompt answer. If you want to mark that as an answer, I'm happy to accept it as the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=162c915aee21684e127a0dae276a5451)

Using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT
    stddev_samp(return_val) OVER(ORDER BY curr_date)
FROM
    mytable
```